Troubleshooting Samsung AC error code
recently my Samsung AC unit (model AR12RXFPEWQNEU) started throwing error E251 repeatedly and won't start.
So I looked up the manual and saw that the issue was related to the temperature sensor in the outdoor unit.
To try and troubleshoot myself I probed the resistance of the sensor and saw that it had a reasonable value (265k Ohm) and it fell within the range of acceptable values.
I'm not sure how to continue with my investigation though, because the PCB is a multi layer one and the components are mostly SMD with tiny traces.
Most videos I saw online suggested to replace the whole board (in case of sensor failure) if the sensors appeared to be functioning, but as I enjoy learning and trying to fix stuff myself, I was wondering if I had other options in order to avoid paying for more than half the cost of the whole AC just for the board.
I was thinking I could power up the PCB while it disconnected from the rest of the system and see if it overheats in some unusual way, using my thermal camera, to single out shorted components or something like that.
Do I have any other alternatives besides this? Thanks
